# How to customize field value in a view for a block based on the current URL or path?

Tags: drupal-7, view, block

I'm using Drupal 7 and have a view that lists some content with links to the full articles.  The content is filtered based on the path using taxonomy terms.  I would like to update the links to the article based on same filter.

For example I have a vocabulary with the terms Start, Grow, Move.
The pages are tagged with the terms like:

```
Child1 (start, grow)
Child2 (start, move)
Child3 (grow, move)
Child4 (start, grow)
```

For the url `http://domain.com/start` I get a page with `Child1, Child2, Child4`.  The links for these pages take me to the correct url `domain.com/start/childx`.

For the url `http://domain.com/grow` I get a page with `Child1, Child3, Child4`.  However, the links for these pages take me to

```
domain.com/start/childx 
  instead of 
domain.com/grow/childx
```

Is there any way to grab the current taxonomy term or parse the URL and reuse it when rewriting the link?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using pathauto? Each node can only have one alias as the alias isn't context dependent. For it to work like you want you'll need to write a custom url using maybe a phpfield and a module that displays the correct node for different URLS.

My recommendation is set a different pattern for the URLs as it's the simplest solution.

Comment: I'm using nodesymlink to show the same content in multiple areas.

Comment: But anyways answering your question, you can try to install the PHPField module. Hide your current output and access the output and edit it. As described here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31690/how-to-use-views-php-to-rewrite-results-of-a-field